How to make Dependabot prioritize private registry packages over public registry packages with the same name
I have the following dependabot.yml file in one of my GitHub repositories.
version: 2
registries:
  my-private-nuget-packages:
    type: nuget-feed
    url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ secrets.USERNAME }}/index.json
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
  public-nuget-packages:
    type: nuget-feed
    url: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: nuget
    commit-message:
      prefix: "(dependabot)"
    directory: "/"
    registries:
      - my-private-nuget-packages
      - public-nuget-packages
    schedule:
      interval: daily

This repository references both public packages & some private packages that I publish through GitHub.
One of these private packages has a name that is used in the public registry.
I would prefer to not have to change the name of this package.
Is there a way to tell dependabot that a specific package is coming from the private registry, so that it won't try updating it to match the public registry package?
